# Output error while creating Java Json array object with List and Hashmap

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I want to create an Json array object with List and hashmap, but I have faced some weird problem during the program execution.

This is my code:

```
List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
String raw = "<CONTENT><DETAIL><USER>user1</USER><MAIL>abc@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL><DETAIL><USER>user2</USER><MAIL>def@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL></CONTENT>";
String partRas = "";
int index = raw.indexof("<USER>");

while(index >= 0) {
    if(index + 50 < raw.length())
        partRaw = raw.subString(index, index + 50);

    hmap("user", getTagValue(partRaw, "USER"));
    hmap("email", getTagValue(partRaw, "MAIL"));
    list.add(hmap);

    raw = raw.subString(index + 50, raw.length());
    index = raw.indexof("<USER>");
}

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));


public static String getTagValue(String xml, String tagName){
    return xml.split("<"+tagName+">")[1].split("</"+tagName+">")[0];
}
```

This code looks legit, but when I executed this code, I was expected to have the result like this:

```
[{"user":"user1","email":"abc@test.com"},{"user":"user2","email":"def@test.com"}]
```

but what I got is this:

```
[{"user":"user2","email":"def@test.com"},{"user":"user2","email":"def@test.com"}]
```

The only answer to this problem I could figure is "**it is PASS BY ADDRESS**", so my first result pushed into List were affected by the second iteration.

The question I want to ask: **Does anyone know the way to get the result I wanted?**

I don't expect the answer to tell me to define multiple HashMaps at the beginning because my raw data might contain more "", which meant it could contain as many of "USER" and "MAIL" data as possible.

Comment: This code isn't an [mcve].  In particular it does not show where `map` is defined.  If I was going to guess, that's your problem.  You're not creating a new instance of `map` every time you start parsing a new user entry - so the values in the old one just keep getting over-written. (`hmap` is supposed to be `map` maybe?).

Comment: typing error, now it has been corrected.

Comment: @Tibrogargan does that mean I have to dynamically define new HashMap at every iteration inside the while-loop?

Comment: I'll do an answer, easier to just show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hmap` is being reused in your code, the values are being overwritten, so when you add it to the list you're just adding a new reference to the same thing.

```
List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, String> hmap;
String raw = "<CONTENT><DETAIL><USER>user1</USER><MAIL>abc@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL><DETAIL><USER>user2</USER><MAIL>def@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL></CONTENT>";
String partRas = "";
int index = raw.indexof("<USER>");

while(index >= 0) {
    if(index + 50 < raw.length())
        partRaw = raw.subString(index, index + 50);

    /*
     * Create a new, empty HashMap 
     */
    hmap = new HashMap<>();
    hmap("user", getTagValue(partRaw, "USER"));
    hmap("email", getTagValue(partRaw, "MAIL"));
    list.add(hmap);

    raw = raw.subString(index + 50, raw.length());
    index = raw.indexof("<USER>");
}

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));

public static String getTagValue(String xml, String tagName){
    return xml.split("<"+tagName+">")[1].split("</"+tagName+">")[0];
}
```

You may actually want to check this out (even though error checking is woeful):

```
String raw = "<CONTENT><DETAIL><USER>user1</USER><MAIL>abc@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL><DETAIL><USER>user2</USER><MAIL>def@test.com</MAIL></DETAIL></CONTENT>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

try {
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw.getBytes()));
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("DETAIL");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(idx);
        System.out.println("User: "+((Element)node).getElementsByTagName("USER").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Mail: "+((Element)node).getElementsByTagName("MAIL").item(0).getTextContent());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: hmm, look like I have no other option but use the dynamic define. I thought the `add()` function of List was pass by value, but after this bug I think I was wrong.

Comment: @Kaninchen java doesn't do pass by value except for primitive types.

Comment: learned too much of pointer stuff before, so this bug confused me because I didn't see `*` or `&` at function's parameters field on oracle doc. That's why I think it is pass by value before.